# Unable to either Restart or Shutdown my Install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ( No Dual Boot ) on Acer Aspire ES1-512

Tags: shutdown, restart

I am puzzled as to why my machine does not shutdown within my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation on my Acer (UEFI Boot Mode).

I go into the whole "**Shutdown**" process, starts looking like it is about to shutdown, shows me the Ubuntu logo and just hangs there. I have to physically hold down the power button, to shutdown my laptop.

Any workarounds/fixes that will solve this issue?

BTW, when trying to restart my machine, I actually get a blinking cursor then just a blank screen. Machine is still on  but nothing happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible fix here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217602

Comment: Unfortunately this potential fix did not work for me. Ubuntu shuts down but not the machine.

Comment: Too bad.  You've certainly had your full quota of issues on this install :(

Comment: Looks that way. Still progressing with it and hopefully there is a fix for this shutdown issue. Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze on shutdown/restart and randomly - Xubuntu 15.10 - Acer Aspire ES1-512](http://askubuntu.com/questions/719287/freeze-on-shutdown-restart-and-randomly-xubuntu-15-10-acer-aspire-es1-512)

Answer (score 2):

I spent a weeks with solving this problem on the same ntb as your without any progress. Yesterday I finally found the thread. In the bios you have to disable xHCI support (USB 3.0). After that my Acer works perfectly (shutting down, restart, sleep mode).

Here is the forum where I've found the help:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195407

Answer (score 0):

try insert in grub command line (etc/default/grub) the "restart=acpi halt=acpi poweroff=acpi" commands, update in terminal (sudo update-grub)

if work then install 64 bit version and update it when install done.