# Freeze on shutdown/restart and randomly - Xubuntu 15.10 - Acer Aspire ES1-512

Tags: xubuntu, acer

I recently bought an Acer Aspire ES1-512. I wiped the disk and installed Xubuntu 15.10 64bit (dual boot with Windows 7 - BIOS, not UEFI).

When I started using Xubuntu, I realized that at random points, it completely freezes with the screen retaining it's contents but nothing being responsive, and the only possibility being to hold the power button and force a restart.

I also noticed that initiating a shutdown or a restart or a standby all result in the same problem (the freeze).

To test whether older versions of the OS don't have the problem, I tried installing a bunch of them on a flash drive and trying a live boot. All of the versions 14.04.3-desktop-amd64 / 15.04-desktop-amd64 / 15.10-desktop-amd64 had the same problem (freeze on shutdown), however 14.10-desktop-amd64 shuts down successfully.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I tried turning off ACPI by adding acpi=off to /etc/default/grub, and I noticed that this solves the random freezes, but it didn't solve the shutdown/restart problem. Also, turning off ACPI disabled some features like keyboard media (fn) keys and the built-in MMC card reader as well as the battery meter, so this is not a good solution..

EDIT: I tried a memtest for 10+ hours and it passed.

Comment: Having to hold the power button is annoying; perhaps next time you could try [holding the left ALT and SysRq buttons and pressing B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). I have noticed that in case of a freeze, this often reboots the system.

Comment: Note: This fix works for the acer e5-511. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524894/boot-and-shutdown-issues-on-aspire-e-11-model-e3-111-c0wa

Comment: @cameron: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that to no avail.

Comment: [Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2285694) suggests shutdown/reboot issues can be worked around by blacklisting dw_dmac and dw_dmac_core.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/594649/unable-to-either-restart-or-shutdown-my-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-lts-no-dual-bo

Comment: @bain: The answer to the question you linked to (disabling xHCI) has actually solved the shutdown/restart problem, I have now removed "acpi=off" to test if disabling xHCI also solves the random freezing problem. If you want, you can post this as an answer to my question and I'll keep testing the laptop and if I realized this also solves the random freezing problem, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Random freezing also doesn't seem to be happening anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been reports of Acer laptops failing to shutdown or restart properly with some recent kernels. Disabling XHCI USB3 support in the BIOS seems to workaround the issue. This will have the disadvantage of slowing down any USB3 devices to USB2 speeds. It is probably the same USB3 issue  reported as [bug #1485057](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1485057) which is likely to be fixed in recent kernels, so you could installing a recent mainline kernel instead of disabling USB3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to the shutdown problems:

> [...] In the BIOS settings I had to **disable the "xHCI support (external USB 3.0 controller)"**. Maybe not the best solution, but it works for me.
>
> Also, it's worth mentioning that I disabled UEFI in the BIOS and using legacy mode instead [...]

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1529860#p1529860

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Acer ES1-512. I tried ubuntu, mint, loki, freya, manjaro and they all had the same problem, they didn't shutdown. 
Then I figured it that there must be a problem with the pc and not with the os.
After a few minutes looking in BIOS I saw that boot was in legacy mode. 
I sitched it to UEFI and reinstalled os. After that everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the version of X.Org shipped in the newer versions (14.04.2+ gets the X.org version from 15.04).  This laptop seems to use Intel Graphics, try getting the latest version at:  https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1.  This might allow 15.10 to work if the bug has been fixed.  As a workaround you could use Xubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: Thanks, but I tried installing the latest version and it didn't fix the shutdown problem..

Comment: Did you update the BIOS?

Comment: yes, tried that as well

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problems with my Acer ES1-711 laptop, and all is started when bios was upgraded from version 1.02 to 1.05 (Insydeh20). After much searching on forums (firstly i'm not suspected the bios has fault because on those days i tried many distros and was thinking problem is created by some package from downloaded updates, kernel or so...) finally decided to downgrade bios to a previous 1.02 version and problem is gone, at least now i can to properly shut down or restart...Recently the Xubuntu 15.10 kernel was upgraded to 4.2.0-27(from .0-25), will see how system is going now, if any problem - i'll post here a message, if all is ok - then problem created by bios, at least for me. p.s. "suggests shutdown/reboot issues can be worked around by blacklisting dw_dmac and dw_dmac_core. – bain Jan 13 at 17:11" - had to do this with EVERY distro of linux, if not - problem whit shutdown/restart persists(but not freezes). Cheers!